# How did the card get into the vault in Now You See Me?

Tags: plot-explanation, now-you-see-me

In the movie *Now You See Me*, the 'Four Horsemen' rob a French bank and later reveal that the robbery was

> all an illusion.

I understood the trick, but what I don’t get is **how the signed card and the show poster ended up in the bank in France**?

Comment: **THADDEUS:** *They made counterfeit cash out of this paper-and I'll thank you not to ask me how counterfeit cash is made. They treated it several hours before entering the vault, then switched it with the real money, so that no one would notice anything was missing. In the minimum time remaining they escaped with the real cash, made it to Vegas and on-stage in time for the show. They do their bit, the guards in Paris fling open the vault door and on cue-pffff.* - https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/now-you-see-me-2013.pdf. With access to the vault, they could've left *anything*

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Now_You_See_Me_(film)#:%7E:text=Thaddeus%20demonstrates%20how%20the%20Horsemen,creating%20any%20smoke%20or%20residue.) explains..

> Thaddeus demonstrates how the Horsemen used a mock vault under the Las Vegas stage, and explains that they stole the money before it arrived at the bank, replacing it with flash paper designed to look like the money, which ignited when the vents were activated without creating any smoke or residue.

The card etc. was placed in the vault with the fake cash and was the only thing left once it ignited.